# Need help in Bashscript for monthwise

Tags: bash

I've a directory name `date` which contains files from jan to dec, for example file name `jan.sh`, `feb.sh` until `dec.sh`. Now I want to make a bash script that will copy each file to `xyz` directory on the first day of each month. On jan it will copy `jan.sh` and on `feb.sh` and so on until the month of dec.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

```sh
CURRENT_MONTH=$(date "+%b")  # e.g. The display depends on locale (LANG environment variable)
cp "${CURRENT_MONTH}.sh" destination_dir  # Adjust the formatting of source name according to the display of date
```

Comment: Or shorter `cp "$(date "+%b.sh")" destination_dir` and if it all need to be small letter : `cp "$(date "+%b.sh" | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]')" destination_dir`

Comment: On my Ubuntu PC,  "date +%b" returns exactly "oct.", not "Oct". The output may depend on the "date" version (on my PC iti is "date (GNU coreutils) 8.30"). So, it is better to pass a filter like "tr" to translate everything in lower/upper cases as needed.
But pay attention to the fact that "my date" version also adds a dot at the end. You need also check this.

Comment: After a check to the help of the command, the display of "date" depends on the locale.

         ==> LANG=C : date +%b returns oct.
         ==> LANG=en_US : date +%b returns Oct